# Overlay contour plot on imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I am having trouble producing an overlay with contour plot and imshow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

def f(x, y):
    return (1 - x / 2 + x ** 5 + y ** 3 ) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)

n = 100
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 3 * n)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 3 * n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.hot, origin='lower')
contours = plt.contour(X, Y, f(X,Y), 10, colors='black')
plt.clabel(contours, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.savefig('overlay_image.pdf', dpi=72)
plt.show()
```

The resulting picture has the contour plot forced into the bottom left hand corner:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Dtf.png]

How is it possible to get a contour overlay on top of the image?

Comment: Is this CMB? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the extent of the `imshow`, so that the coordinates line up with those used in the `contour` plot.

From the [`imshow` docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

> extent : floats (left, right, bottom, top), optional
>
> The bounding box in data coordinates that the image will fill.
> The image is stretched individually along x and y to fill the box.

So you could use:

```
extent = x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()
plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', 
           cmap=plt.cm.hot, origin='lower',
           extent=extent)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not displaying `x,y` coordinates, another option is to remove `X,Y` arguments in `contour`, so that that coordinates are running from `0` to `n`

```
plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.hot, origin='lower')
contours = plt.contour(f(X,Y), 10, colors='black')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is “right” but really the wrong direction in terms of getting unitized x and y on the axes.

Comment: @JodyKlymak agreed, hence the first sentence of the answer. Sometimes ppl don't care about `x,y` and this simplifies their code base. I think that's partially why `X,Y` are not required on `contour`.