# Adding Numbered Contour Lines to a 2D Heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, heatmap, contour

[image: starting plot]

I want to add labelled contour lines to a 2D heat map. The color represents the value of the data, which are all floats. The grey areas aren't important, these have been set to NaN for other reasons. Here is my code to generate the graph:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from scipy import ndimage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set_theme(style='dark')
im = ax.imshow(data,cmap='turbo') 
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax = ax,cmap='turbo')
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("Cost ($B)", rotation = -90, va = "bottom")
ax. grid(True)
ax.set_facecolor('dimgrey')
```

I tried using,
[Contour (iso-z) or threshold lines in seaborn heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011748/contour-iso-z-or-threshold-lines-in-seaborn-heatmap)
but this didn't work.

I tried looking at this,
[Overlay contour plot on imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69885183/overlay-contour-plot-on-imshow)
but my data is a 2D array of floats, not seperate x,y,z values.

Comment: Since your x and y values are just integers (that's how an image map works), you can get obtain x and y data with NumPy's `meshgrid`. Then you have 2D x, y and z data, in correct order, with which you can create the contour plot. In fact, this is what happens in the question of your second link: the answer is already there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay contour plot on imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69885183/overlay-contour-plot-on-imshow)

Comment: By the way, heat maps should be created using `ax.pcolormesh` since `imshow` is for images (as the name implies).

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that overlay contour, x,y=np.meshgrid(data) didn't work?

Comment: I have found a solution, contours=plt.contour(data, colors='white')
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=8)

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to hop on a high level visualization package (plotly) instead of the fundamental matplotlib. It might be easier to implement.
FYI only

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

feature_x = np.arange(0, 50, 2)
feature_y = np.arange(0, 50, 3)

# Creating 2-D grid of features
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(feature_x, feature_y)

Z = np.cos(X / 2) + np.sin(Y / 4)

fig = go.Figure(data =
    go.Contour(
        x = feature_x, 
        y = feature_y, 
        z = Z, 
        contour=dict(
            start=1,
            end=5,
            size=.2, showlabels=True
            )))

fig.show()
```